# Why I cannot access admin page Orchard Core (error 404)?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcore

I developped a website using Orchard Core CMS.
When I'm using my localhost I can access the default Admin Page to create blogs, articles etc.

But after using the 'publish' option on visual studio and put it on a server, I cannot access the default admin page anymore, I get a 404 error.

Can someone tell me why ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you include the app_data folder? Can you see anything other than the admin page?

Comment: Yes I did include the app_data folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that you needed to create the table in your Database manually and add permission to IIS and Users on files/folders